# SQL Server conditional where clause in case no rows are fetched

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a table that holds IP's either exact or masked for example:

- `192.168.99.5` is an exact IP and
- `192.168.99.*` or `192.*.*.7` are examples of masked IP

I need to create a query that returns the matching ip I'll give an example

Suppose I have an entry of `192.168.99.*` in my database.

If I would run

```
select * 
from myTable 
where IP = '192.168.99.65'
```

it should return the row, since the last segment of the IP is wildcard so any number should fit.

Yet if I run

```
select * 
from myTable 
where IP = '192.169.99.65'
```

it must not retrieve that row.

I also need this to be efficient...

What is the correct way to approach this?

Comment: `where ? replace(ip, '*', '%')`?

Comment: How do masked IPs play into it? For example, are there scenarios where you query something like `192.168.99.65` and want to return `192...65`? Also, would you ever query or could your IPs ever be something like `*.xxx.xxx.xxx` or would the asterisks only appear at the end of IPs?

Comment: @ZLK in the table we will store values like 192.168.99.65 or ip mask like 192.168.*.65 (the mask can be anywhere) another legit value is *.*.*.* which means every IP. when the user queries the table it will ALWAYS be with a complete IP (one without '*' for example 192.168.99.65) and i need to return the rows that match either exactly or through the mask

Comment: One option is to add a persisted computed column (and index it). For example, `ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable ADD WildcardIP AS CAST(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(IP, 1, 1) = '.' THEN '%' ELSE '' END + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(IP, '*', '%'), '...', '.%.%.'), '..', '.%.') + CASE WHEN RIGHT(IP, 1) = '.' THEN '%' END AS VARCHAR(15)) PERSISTED;` (it looks complicated but it basically just replaces empty gaps/asterisks with % symbols). Then you'd query it with something like `WHERE @val LIKE WildcardIP`. I'm not sure exactly how performant this would be compared to other options, but it should be relatively quick.